# Is it possible to control volume by hovering and scrolling anywhere in the macOS menu bar like what I can do with "7+ Taskbar Tweaker?"

Tags: mac

I use both Macs and PCs. Macs are great but here's one thing
I can do on my PCs that I have not been able to find how to do
in macOS.

On my PCs (Windows 7 and Windows) I have a utility called "7+ Taskbar Tweaker."

That has an option to allow me to control the speaker volume
by putting the mouse anywhere in the taskbar and as I scroll
up/down while the mouse is still in the taskbar the volume
changes up/down:

[image]

This is really very handy and so much more efficient than how
volume control is done in macOS where one has to:

- Mouse up to the menu bar.
- Click on the speaker.
- Mouse over to the speaker slide.
- Scroll and adjust the volume.

I'm hoping there is a way to have the same ability in a Mac that
I have in my PCs i.e., to control the volume by simply mousing
up to anywhere in the Menu bar and then simply scrolling up/down
to change the volume up/down.

Does anyone have any suggestions or know of a way to have this in a Mac?

Comment: Voting to close because what is being asked is not a Windows versus macOS equivalent, but rather a software recommendation based on a user installed Windows app called "7+ Taskbar Tweaker."